# Stop and run timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple countdown timer which can be set by + or - divs and also it can be stopped and run by clicking on itself.My problem is when it is stopped and then runs it shows NAN for the first number.I suppose it is because of `setTimer` function but I don't know how to fix that.

```html
 <div class='session'>2</div>
 <div id='increase' onclick='decrease()'>-</div>
 <div id='increase' onclick='increase()'>+</div>
 <div class='session' onclick='setSession();general()'>2</div>
```

```js
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('session');
var y=document.getElementById('break');
var seconds=60;


function increase(){
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].innerHTML++;
 }
}

function decrease(){
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i].innerHTML>0){
        x[i].innerHTML--;
     }
   }
}

var session;
function setSession(){
  session = x[1].innerHTML - 1;
}

function timer() {
   if (seconds > 0) {
     seconds--;
     if (seconds == 0 && session > 0) {
          session--;
          seconds = 60;
        }
   }
     x[1].innerHTML = session + ':' + seconds;
  }

function stoptimer(){
    clearInterval(t);
}

  var t;
 var on=true;
 function general(){
   if(on){  
      on=false;
      t=setInterval(timer,100);
  }else{  
     on=true;
    stoptimer();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your setSession() method is where the NaN error comes up. Every time you click on the timer to stop it, it subtracts 1 from the innerHTML of

```
<div class='session' onclick='setSession();general()'>2</div>
```

If the timer has started, the innerHTML is **text** of the form

```
number:number
```

...which is what causes the error. Trying to subtract 1 from something like that leads to undesirable results.

What's the purpose of the session digit? Are you trying to use your session variable as a placeholder for your tens place, or something similar? Why not just keep it all as a single digit and convert to the appropriate string when updating the html?

Comment: Well, when not using setTimer function, my timer doesn't  start from the new  duration but starts from the given duration ,in this case from 2.

Comment: I would suggest starting with a number rather than setting your session variable to HTML. This will help prevent any type conversions that javascript natively does between strings and numbers

Comment: Here's an example of some fixes you can try. It's not perfect, but it's a start: https://plnkr.co/edit/eRYYrOPG20odnJ31v600?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very very  much for your help :)